# How do I calculate the standard deviation of all values in a column that are greater thant a certain number in Libre Office?

Tags: statistics, libreoffice-calc

Consider a column of a spread sheet, e.g. column `A` in the picture.

How can I get Libre Office to calculate the standard deviation of this column, but **without considering values below a certain threshold** (`A14` in the picture)?

In the picture my desired expression, would only consider the values of cells `A1`, `A4`, `A7` to `A9`, `A10` and `A11` in the standard deviation as if they were only ones in the column (sub-sample).

[image: LibreOffice conditional deciation]

As you can see I tried

```
=STDEV(IF(A1:A12>A14,A1:A12))
```

...and its array-form to no avail. I'm surprised non of these work as it goes against other claims in the OpenOffice forum and against my intuition of LibreOffice.

**Edit:**
The problems seems to be more of a bug in my version. Even in a fresh sheet it behaves unpredictable. Sometimes I have to remove the last round closing bracket `)`, than enter it manually again and then press <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for array mode. Sometimes it doesn't work at all no matter what I do. Its incredible.

Comment: This formula works for me as array formula - result is `0.1020620726`. Did you enter the curly braces manually? I wonder why the opening bracket is placed **after** the leading equation sign. I think `FORMULA()` should return `{=STDEV(IF(A1:A12>A14,A1:A12))}` instead (opening bracket `{` before `=`)... (tested with LO Calc 4.4.2.2)

Comment: I'm very puzzled. Now the formula sheet is behaving completely erratic. The problem seems to be something else bug related.

Comment: Hmm - i've just tested it with LO Calc 4.2.7.2 on Linux Mint 17 (same build ID as yours) - works perfectly, too... BTW - forget to mention - **don't** insert the curly braces manually - Calc will add them automatically when entering as array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

Comment: @tohuwawohu Why not to convert your comments into an answer?